# ZF2 - \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression and DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2.4 and trying to amend a working SQL columns select from

```
'content_publish_date' => 'publish_date',
```

to

```
'content_publish_date' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('DATE_FORMAT(\'content.publish_date\',\'%d/%c/%Y\')'),
```

produces the following SQL...

```
DATE_FORMAT('content.publish_date','%%d/%%c/%%Y') AS `content_publish_date`,
```

... which fails syntactically on MySQL (note the extra '%')

I have tried various alternatives...

```
'content_publish_date' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('DATE_FORMAT(content.publish_date,\'%d/%c/%Y\')'),
'content_publish_date' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('DATE_FORMAT(content.publish_date,"%d/%c/%Y")'),
```

... and so on, none of which has helped.

Does anyone have any idea how to use the Expression correctly to get the correct generated SQL?

The full code for this piece is as follows:

```
        $dbSelect->join(
            'content',
            'content.id = category.content_id',
            array(
                'content_title'             => 'title',
                'content_html_title'        => 'html_title',
                'content_description'       => 'description',
                'content_content_text'      => 'content_text',
                'content_url'               => 'url',
                'content_url_vars'          => 'url_vars',
                'content_meta_keyword'      => 'meta_keyword',
                'content_meta_description'  => 'meta_description',
                'content_content_type_id'   => 'content_type_id',
                'content_disclaimer_id'     => 'disclaimer_id',
                'content_agent_target_id'   => 'agent_target_id',
                'content_video_position'    => 'video_position',
                'content_video_size'        => 'video_size',
                'content_creation_date'     => 'creation_date',
                'content_publish_date'      => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('DATE_FORMAT(\'content.publish_date\',\'%d/%c/%Y\')'),
                'content_flag_content_url'  => 'flag_content_url',
                'content_flags'             => 'flags'
            ),
            \Zend\Db\Sql\Select::JOIN_LEFT
        );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me. What is the minor version of ZF you are using?

Comment: Spot on akond, upgraded to 2.4.9, from 2.4.0 and voila! Thanks.